# Enum values depending on controller site in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, enums, thymeleaf

My enum:

```
public enum ADD_OR_EDIT {

    ADD("/user/add", "addForm"), EDIT("/user/edit", "editForm");

    private String thAction;
    private String thObject;

    ADD_OR_EDIT(String thAction, String thObject) {
        this.thAction = thAction;
        this.thObject = thObject;
    }
    //getters and setters ommited to clear view
}
```

My controller line for edit

```
addAttribute("addOrEdit", ADD_OR_EDIT.EDIT);
```

My controller line for add:

```
addAttribute("addOrEdit", ADD_OR_EDIT.ADD);
```

The question is how to fix my thymeleaf form to get value depending on that.

For example:

```
   <form action="#" th:action="(@{addOrEdit.thAction})" class="form-horizontal form-narrow" th:object="${addOrEdit.thObject}"
      method="post">
```

(This one doesn't work)

UPDATE:

The problem is with the second parameter of enum - thObject.

in add:

```
model.addAttribute("basicForm", basicForm);
model.addAttribute("addOrEdit",ADD_OR_EDIT.ADD);
```

in edit:

```
model.addAttribute("editForm", editForm);
model.addAttribute("addOrEdit",ADD_OR_EDIT.EDIT);
```

Maybe the value of th:object is "addForm" instead of addForm and this cause an error.

UPDATE2:

This one works:

```
<form action="#" th:action="(${addOrEdit.thAction})" class="form-horizontal form-narrow" th:object="(${basicForm})"
      method="post">
```

This one works also:

```
<form action="#" th:action="(${addOrEdit.thAction})" class="form-horizontal form-narrow" th:object="(${editForm})"
      method="post">
```

So the case now is to connect them by enum like we did on thAction:
This doesnt work:

```
<form action="#" th:action="(${addOrEdit.thAction})" class="form-horizontal form-narrow" th:object="(${{addOrEdit.thObject})"
      method="post">
```

Comment: what are you expecting to do with this form? Why do you need form and not simple link for example, do you want to submit some info to the server?

Comment: I want to use one form to do edit and add instead of two separated forms, and I have two separated controllers for add and edit

Comment: can you also post `editForm`/`basicForm` class because if those are 2 different classes, i don't think you will be able to use single form for them

Comment: Thats why I try to use enum, to use two different classes.

Comment: But one class extends the second one so all <inputs> are fine, thats not the problem.

Comment: This can solve my problem. Let me check this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `th:action="${addOrEdit.thAction}"` instead of `th:action="@{addOrEdit.thAction}"`

***update***:

```
model.addAttribute("form", basicForm);
model.addAttribute("addOrEdit",ADD_OR_EDIT.ADD);
in edit:

model.addAttribute("form", editForm);
model.addAttribute("addOrEdit",ADD_OR_EDIT.EDIT);


<form action="#" th:action="(${addOrEdit.thAction})" class="form-horizontal form-narrow" th:object="${form}"
      method="post">
```

Comment: post your output of the html.there must be something wrong in your project ,but not here , because it does work in my machine

Comment: I know where is the problem, give me a second I'll update answer so you'll know everything and maybe u'll help me somehow :)

Comment: why not use the same attribute name,then set defferent object in each controller,thus `th:ojbect` can be a constant string value

Comment: And this will be probably a right answer. Just give me a second to check it :)

Comment: I think varren's answer is feasible too,but not as direct

Comment: after fixing problem with second parameter came another one with the first one.
2017-12-05 13:18:26.795 ERROR 7336 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "userAddEdit": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "addOrEdit.thAction" (template: "userAddEdit" - line 14, col 22)

and " Property or field 'thAction' cannot be found on null"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160512/discussion-between-neo-and-degath).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what kind of info you want to POST. if it is some User pojo, then you will have to include every field in your form. The basic case would look something like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{${addOrEdit.thAction}}"
      class="form-horizontal form-narrow" th:object="${__${addOrEdit.thObject}__}"
      method="post">

    <!--FIELDS YOU WANT TO SUBMIT-->
    <input name="id" type="text" th:value="*{id}" hidden="hidden"/>
    <input name="name" type="text" th:value="*{name}" hidden="hidden"/>
    <input name="gender" type="text" th:value="*{gender}" hidden="hidden"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I updated question so u can check what is the real problem I think. Th action works well and the problem is with th:object

Comment: give me a second to test it :)

Comment: @degath i actually think you should use neo suggestion and change model form name in controller. And probably you can pass from controller `form` and `url` and  remove enum completely.

Comment: I accepted neo answer, but your help was great too. 
Really appreciate your help and involving in my problem.
Have a nice day :)